# Word command-line-arguments space issues

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, command-line-arguments

I want to pass parameters to winword in order to read it in my vsto addin by using Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().

If a parameter-value contains a space I'm not able to escape the strings.

This is working:

```
winword.exe /myVar1:C:\folder\whatever1.doc /myVar2:C:\folder\somethingelese.txt C:\example.doc
```

This is not working:

```
winword.exe /myVar1:"C:\folder with space\whatever1.doc" /myVar2:"C:\folder with space 2\somethingelese.txt" C:\example.doc
```

Comment: If you haven't completely abandoned this, I noticed that the second example works for me when opening a Word 2007 template. Were you using a different version of Word?

Answer (score 2):

Try with the following command :

```
winword.exe "/myVar1:C:\folder with space\whatever1.doc" "/myVar2:C:\folder with space 2\somethingelese.txt" C:\example.doc
```

If it still doesn't work, send us the content of the array returned by GetCommandLineArgs.

Comment: What is the array returned by GetCommandLineArgs ? The bug may be in your code (maybe you are not reading the values properly).

Comment: here is the content
-  args {string[2]} string[]
  [0] "winword.exe" string
  [1] "/myVar1:C:\\folder with space\\whatever1.doc" string

Comment: no. its a new instance. im sure its just a syntax problem ... without the quotes and spaces everything is ok :(