# Winword.exe ignores parameters AFTER one parameter with quotes

Tags: command-line, ms-word

My problem from [Word command-line-arguments space issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321814/word-command-line-arguments-space-problem) seems to be a specific winword.exe problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=VS.90%29.aspx says: MyApp.exe "alpha with spaces" "beta with spaces" ==> MyApp.exe, alpha with spaces, beta with spaces

This is not true for winword.exe.

```
winword.exe /alpha:1 /beta:2 ==> OK  
winword.exe "/alpha:1 space" "/beta:2" ==> beta is missing?!    
winword.exe /alpha:"1 space" "/beta:2" ==> beta is missing?!
```

It's really odd ... I'm not able to pass more than one parameter that contains spaces.
any ideas?

Comment: duplicate and repeat question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321814/word-command-line-arguments-space-problem. If you have new input for a question edit the original one